# PHP Website Logging users out after inactivity

Tags: php, session-cookies, session-variables, session-state

Included in every page is a PHP file with:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 86400);
```

On login there is this:
`$_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 24 * 60 * 60 );`

I want to keep the users logged in even if they step away from their computer screens. For the moment if you are inactive even for a short while it kicks you to the login page. What else can I do to increase the amount of time a user is logged in?

Comment: You've got something else at play here, your cookie lifetime is a day and your session expiration is five days.

Comment: Beware `ini_set` does not always work depending on the server configuration. Make sure the `ini_set` calls don't return false

Comment: bring your own logic using a cookie. this will enable you to auto-login immediately when logged out using that cookie. the user won't notice any difference. see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73778373/3807365) for a recipe