# How to Increase User Login Session Time in PHP

Tags: php

I made a simple Login in PHP based on tutorials, where the user after logging in is saved in the Session variable like the example below.

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username
```

The problem is that the login session is automatically closed after closing the browser, obligating the user to always start the login process all over again and again.

How I can keep the user logged in for a week or a month? (Like Facebook and others) What is the proper and safe way to do it?

Comment: You need to make a "remember me" functionality. This isn't the same as just extending the session...the session always ends when the browser closes (or before that, if the server session timeout setting is exceeded). There will be examples online you can follow already, I'm [quite sure](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+login+remember+me)

Comment: I believe that's exactly what I'm looking for, currently trying to find a good example that is also safe for production, let me know if you know a good example. Thanks!

Comment: here's an [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73778373/3807365) that worked for me